# .sendkeys method not working to upload file using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate facebook marketplace posts. But i'm struggling to upload pictures to it.

I already locate the element. When i click the element it will show the 'box' showing the file manager so that i can click on the folders and then the desired image.

```
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="rc.js_c"]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/div/a/div[2]')))
ele.click()
```

But when i try this:

```
ele.send_keys('/file_path/rasp.jpeg')
```

It raises this exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

I also tried using the os library:

```
ele.send_keys(os.getcwd() + '/home/br1/Downloads/rasp.jpeg')
```

Getting the same exception error.

The html code where the element is visible (element used in code):

```
<div class="_3jk">
```

which is the parent of (where the element is not visible):

```
<input accept="image/*" multiple="" name="composer_photo" title="Elige un archivo para subir" data-testid="add-more-photos" display="inline-block" type="file" class="_n _5f0v" id="js_wg">
```

Here is all the code if you want to try it:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 10 
 # driver protocols
 options = Options()
 options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
 options.add_argument('start-maximized')
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/chromedriver')
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
 # url
 driver.get('http://facebook.com/marketplace')
 driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 # logging
 driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('username')
 driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('password')
 driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_2').click()
 # entering marketplace
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Vender algo")]').click()
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Artículo en venta")]').click()
 ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="rc.js_c"]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/div/a/div[2]')))
 ele.send_keys('/file_path/rasp.jpeg')
```

Any ideas and suggestions will be aprecciate it.
I'm a Linux user.

Comment: you need to send keys to the input tag.  (It'll set the 'value' attribute to your path...)

Comment: this is same problem with div upload photo ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268922/python-selenium-sales-group-fb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using the input to send the file path rather the div.

Try the below.

```
ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@name="composer_photo" and @type="file"]')))
ele.send_keys("file_to_be_uploaded")
```

Comment: it worked without using os module. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've tried all possibilities and only the 'Full XPath' Option worked. Can you tell my why? Result of some Elements:
Xpath: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3d4555cb39e167485f17a9ac928c0111", element="E58A64FF0AF08BA0AA4EF76EEDE5EB98_element_292")>
ID: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3d4555cb39e167485f17a9ac928c0111", element="E58A64FF0AF08BA0AA4EF76EEDE5EB98_element_292")>
Full Xpath: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3d4555cb39e167485f17a9ac928c0111", element="E58A64FF0AF08BA0AA4EF76EEDE5EB98_element_299")>