# Selenium VBA: Fill a Windows Popup to upload a file

Tags: vba, windows, selenium, path, popup

I'm not able to have interaction with Windows PopUp to write a dedicated path to upload a file in VBA using Selenium due to Chrome browser.

I have found some solutions in Python but nothing in VBA. This is why I have tried to convert the code in VBA but without success.

Find below an example code:

```
Sub Fullfil_Windows_PopUp()
Dim driver
Dim elem

    Set Waiter = CreateObject("Selenium.Waiter")
    Set Assert = CreateObject("Selenium.Assert")
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")

    'open the browser and the page
    driver.Get "https://fr.imgbb.com/"
    While Waiter.Not(InStr(driver.Title, "ImgBB — Upload Image — Hébergement d'images gratuit")): Wend

    'open upload window
    Set elem = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='home-cover-content']/div[2]/a").Item(1)
    elem.Click

    'Trial 1
    driver.SwitchToWindowByTitle "Ouvrir" '--> NOK (error window not found)
    driver.SendKeys "D:\Test.jpg"

    'Trial 2
    driver.SwitchToAlert.SendKeys "D:\Test.jpg" '--> NOK (error No Alert present)


    'Trial 3
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.SendKeys "D:\Test.jpg" '--> NOK (no action)


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: check if you have `<input type="file"....` element in your dev tools Elements tab. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174422/sendkeys-method-not-working-to-upload-file-using-python-selenium/60175964?noredirect=1#comment106438225_60175964)

Comment: Thanks for answer. See my onters answers if you have any idea in VBA ! Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have used a "back door" to fill the file name into the filemanager window. 
As the cursor is already into the filename field of the window, I have created an external script in VBS to write the file name (and 2x TAB + ENTER to validate the window).

Below the code of the VBS file:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "D:\Test.jpg"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

And I execute this script after to have open the filemanager window with selenium:

```
Sub Fullfil_Windows_PopUp()
Dim driver
Dim elem

    ' Chrome browser
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")

    'open the browser and the page
    driver.Get "https://fr.imgbb.com/"
    Sleep 1000

    ' Open upload window
    Set elem = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='home-cover-content']/div[2]/a").Item(1)
    elem.Click

    ' Write the filename with VBS script
    Set oWsh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oWsh.ShellExecute "D:\filename.vbs"
    Set oWsh = Nothing
    Sleep 1500

End Sub
```

**But I continue to search a solution directly with Selenium** because for example, the filename is directly indicated into the VBS File and this is not easy to use it like a variant.

Answer (score 0):

@Armin's answer works quite well if you are in a similar quandary. I don't know of any other method at present to interact with a file window at upload point.

For more details, a VBS file is a Microsoft VB-Script file. You can create this using Notepad, putting in the code, save as, change file name, include ".vbs" extension and change file type to all files.

If you use the code in the answer as it is, you're likely to be greeted with an unfriendly "Undefined Variable" error so you should declare the variable first as an object:

```
Dim oWsh as Object
```

Depending on your code, you may also be greeted with an error for the "Sleep*" command used. You can change this to using an implicit or explicit "Wait" as needed:

```
driver.Wait 1500
```

Cheers!