# VBA with Selenium - Want to upload image on a specific site by VBA Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

1. Want to upload an image on given site, so i needed required code for this

```
Sub MakeQR()
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#text"

    '#1st display the "Add Logo Image" then want to upload image (by Path)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please check if this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177792/selenium-vba-fill-a-windows-popup-to-upload-a-file

Comment: Brother this is not working, please spare some time for this .. and check this site personally.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can not handle any component which is outside the browser. So we need to take help from some tool other than Selenium. In the case of Excel VBA, we can take help from VB scripting. However, take note that this solution might fail in case the human user continues to use a mouse or keyboard while the script runs.

When the file selector window appears it is already in focus. Thus all we have to do is enter the full path to the image that we want to upload and select Enter. The following VBS code takes input for the image path and enters that into that file selector window.

```
Set args = Wscript.Arguments
Dim filepath
filepath = args(0)
'Wscript.Echo args(0)

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys filepath
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Now save this code as a .vbs file. We will call this file from our Excel Macro.

Excel VBA code

```
Sub MakeQR()
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/#text"

    
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//h3[text()='Add Logo Image']").Click
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//button[normalize-space(text())='Upload Image']").Click
    
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    wsh.Run "CSCRIPT ""<path to .vbs file>"" ""<path to image file to be uploaded>""", windowStyle, waitOnReturn
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
    bot.Quit
    
End Sub
```