# Python Selenium Sales Group FB

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, automation

Can i help me , i have a problem trying get div for upload images on sales group in faceboook.

I have already a code in python where can write automatic text in the form of the sales group but i dont cant upload image in new version facebook , 1 year ago this is posibility but now facebook dont have a input file

Previously the code was as follows

```
**photo_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@type="file"]')
photo_element.send_keys(photo)**
```

But this doesn't work now, I've tried this way,
but add only the text of the route in the facebook search engine

New Code

```
photo_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@aria-label="Agregar fotos"]')
photo_element.send_keys(photo)
```

[DIV photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td4Rh.png)

[CODE DIV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDy6w.png)

Comment: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and the error stack trace.

Comment: Those looks like screenshot from your browser. There is noting that say that just because it looks like that for your browser it will look like that when you fetch the page using Selenium. Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them.

Comment: its correct , this is a screenshot from my pc, the objective is upload picture with script of python but the sales group facebook from now have not a input file now is only a  div and i dont know how to send picture .